# How does one prove that the density of unusual numbers is $\ln 2$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

The Wikipedia page for [unusual number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_number) states that the density of that set is $\ln 2$, and that this was proven by Schroeppel in 1972. The only source that I found for that is the [HAKMEM document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAKMEM), and there is no proof given there, just the statement. Does anyone know a reference for a proof? Thanks.

Comment: If $n$ is "unusual" then its large prime factor $p$ is unique.
To count "unusual" $n \leq x$, sum over prime $p \leq x$
the number of "unusual" $n$ that are multiples of $p$.
The count is $p-1$ if $p \leq \sqrt x$, and $\lfloor x/p \rfloor$ if
$\sqrt x < p \leq x$.  By the Prime Number Theorem (or even Chebyshev),
$\sum_{p \leq \sqrt x} (p-1) \ll x/\log x$.  This leaves essentially
$x \sum_{\sqrt x < p \leq x} 1/p + O(x/\log x)$.  Now use
$\sum_{p \leq y} 1/p = \log\log y + o(1)$ for $y=\sqrt x$ and $y=x$ to get $x (\log\log x - \log\log x^{1/2} + o(1)) = x \log 2 + o(x)$, **QED**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies :  That should really be an answer, not a comment!

Comment: Thanks.  If the OP [original proposer] is willing to accept it as an answer 
I can post it as such.  The question as stated asks for a reference, 
not a proof, and I didn't give a reference.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: $\sum_{p \leq y} 1/p$ equals $\log\log y + M + o(1)$, where $M$ is the Meissel–Mertens constant. Of course the presence of $M$ does not matter for your argument.

Comment: Finch gives a reference to Greene & Knuth, Mathematics for the Analysis of Algorithms, 3rd ed., pages 95-98. It appears those pages are freely accessible at https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-0-8176-4729-2%2F1.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference is Greene and Knuth, Mathematics for the Analysis of Algorithms, 3rd ed., pages 95-98. The section of the book containing those pages may be found at https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-0-8176-4729-2%2F1.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Btw, why is that book not better known? Or maybe it is, but when I think of Knuth, I think of TAOCP, Concrete Math, Surreal Numbers and Things a Computer Scientist Rarely Talks About, but this one seems to have escaped my attention.